# Any set can be assigned a normal topology.

Tags: general-topology

Every set can be well-ordered (by the well-ordering theorem). A well-ordered set is normal (in the order topology). Hence every set can be given a normal topology.

Since a normal topological space is regular, and a regular space
is Hausdorff, any set can be given a regular/Hausdorff topology.

Is the logic correct?

This gives me the feeling that nothing is special about those topological properties, if any set can be assigned
such topology.

But of course, I could also conclude that compactness is meaningless,
since any set can be made into a compact space (indiscrete topology).
Which is nonsense.

I guess I just want to see your thoughts about this.

Comment: Discrete topology on any set is Hausdorff, regular and normal.

Comment: My thoughts about this is that if you treat a set as just a set rather than as some other structure, then it has almost no structure, so of course you can build almost anything on top of it.

Comment: The speciality of a specific topological property cannot be "judged/measured" by purely looking at involved underlying sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that any set can be turned into a normal or Hausdorff or compact space is indeed a completely meaningless and irrelevant information.

What we deal with is **concrete** topological spaces, that arise in **concrete** context and then we try to understand their properties. We may notice that some spaces that we work with share properties, like being normal or compact. This is important, we can generalize some knowledge about them. But usually we don't put an arbitrary topology on an arbitrary set. And even if we do that then there's always a method and reason for how and why we do that. Topologies don't come from thin air.

For example $\mathbb{R}$ is important because of the Euclidean topology. We study it a lot. We can put discrete or antidiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but noone cares, as far as I know such space doesn't arise naturally anywhere.

> This gives me the feeling that nothing is special about those topological properties, if any set can be assigned such topology.

Yes, any set can be given a normal or Hausdorff or compact topology. However this doesn't mean that every topological space is normal, Hausdorff or compact. Some are, some aren't. And those with and without occure in maths naturally, that's why we study those properties.

All in all: topological space is more than just a set. Just like well ordered set is more than a set, a group is more than a set, etc.